# Рекурсия с одномерным массивом

Tags: c++, c, рекурсия, функции

Моя функция:

```
int podchcnt(int arr[])
{
    int res;
    for (int j=1;j<=n;j++)
    {
        if (arr[j]==1)
        {
            res+=1;
            res+=podchcnt(arr[j]);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

---

Компилятор выдает ошибку:

> `invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]`

Почему? Я целочисленной переменной присваиваю целочисленное значение функции. В аргументах у функции указан одномерный массив, в рекурсивном вызове передаю одномерный массив.

---

Полный код: http://pastebin.com/xW8sQiXC. Задан орграф таблицей смежности. Программа должна выдавать количество потомков каждой вершины начиная с первой.

Comment: Ругается на строку "res+=podchcnt(arr[j]);"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я, конечно, не специалист в C++, но по-моему вы здесь `res+=podchcnt(arr[j]);` передаете не массив, а элемент массива (т.е. тип int вместо int[]). Отсюда и ошибка, которая говорит, что нельзя преобразовать int в int[].

Comment: Да, вы правы. Вместо `res+=podchcnt(arr[j]);` в процедуре надо было вызывать `res+=podchcnt(a[j]);`, т.к. a - двумерный массив, a[j]-одномерный в таком случае, arr[j] - просто элемент массива.

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите сами - у вас объявлено

```
int podchcnt(int arr[])
```

т.е. что функция `podchcnt` принимает **массив**, иначе говоря, указатель на его первый элемент.
А что вы ей передаете в `podchcnt(arr[j])`?
Просто элемент...

Вот такая вот нестыковка и приводит к проблемам.

Не вдавался в задачу, но могу предположить, что вы хотите передать подмассив, начиная с `j`-го элемента? Тогда пишите либо `arr+j`, либо `&arr[j]`.

И еще - напомню, что счет элементов в массиве начинается с **нуля**, так что вызывает определенные сомнения цикл `for (int j=1;j<=n;j++)`, как, впрочем, и прочие циклы в вашем полном тексте.

Еще - у вас использована неинициализированная переменная `res` - она **не имеет начального значения**, в ней может быть, что угодно, так что результат может быть любым :) Инициализируйте ее, объявив как `int res = 0;`.

Ваша рекурсия вряд ли будет конечной - только если все `arr[j]` не будут единицами - так как в каждом ее вызове будет выполняться один и тот же цикл, без конца делающий одни и те же вызовы. При этом, поскольку вы будете передавать все меньшие участки массива, будет выход за границы массива со всеми (неприятными) последствиями...

Ну и еще - в данном случае это не ошибка, просто получается не совсем... даже слова не подберу. Не совсем красиво, что ли - передавать массив как параметр, а его размер - как глобальную переменную. Передавайте уж оба значения как параметры - тогда функция окажется куда универсальнее. Для рекурсии это тоже важно.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему должно быть так:

```
res+=podchcnt(arr + j);
```

Так как функция принимает массив (считай указатель), то и передавать надо указатель, а не целое число.

Правда, в данном случае надо не забывать, что из-за рекурсии цикл по остаточной части уже должен быть меньше. Правильнее передавать длину (глобальная `n`) вместе с указателем в функцию. Но это уже совсем другая история.